# Transfer traffic between iptable chains

Tags: linux, iptables, transparent-proxy

My understanding is that **normally** any given packet will only ever interact with one iptables chain either INPUT FORWARD or OUTPUT. However I want to have all traffic on port 80 that has neither its source or destination as the current machine (starts on the FORWARD chain) redirected *to* the current machine's port 3219 (ends up on the INPUT chain). The purpose of this is I am running a transparent proxy and this machine is the network's router.

An iptables command and an explanation would be ideal but if you have to choose I would definitely prefer an explanation.

Comment: Your second para has nothing to do with your first.  To work with traffic that's simply passing through the machine, you get to it via the `FORWARD` chain.  Whether or not it passes through any other `filter` chains is immaterial.

Comment: @MadHatter Would you suggest removing para 1?

Comment: And the title, since if para 2 describes what you want to **do**, para 1 and the title are kind of irrelevant.  Alternatively, could you explain more clearly why the only-traversing-one-chain thing is a problem.

Comment: There are many articles on setting up a transparent proxy under Linux. What have you read so far, and what didn't work?

Comment: I was more hoping for an explanation to what this, for example, is doing:
*iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.1:3128  
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My understanding is that normally any given packet will only ever interact with one iptables chain either INPUT FORWARD or OUTPUT.

Your understanding is false, or at best simplistic.  A packet will usually be processed on at least 3 separate tables and various chains on these tables.  When you are looking only at the filter table, then a packet normally will only fit IMPUT/OUTPUT/FORWARD.  But on the other tables, you will hit multiple chains, at different stages.  For example a packet being routed from one interface to another will hit the PREROUTING, and POSTROUTING chains on the nat table.

There are [various flow diagrams](https://www.google.com/search?q=iptables%20diagram%20flow&safe=strict&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X) you can find for iptables.  But none of them really will give you a perfect understanding of what is going on, but look through a bunch of them.  Usually you should be able to get an understanding when you look at them together.